# Adding custom private channel for broadcasting notification in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Broadcasting works but it uses `notifiable_type` as channel name with user id. But what if I want to change only on backend api that some model is within 10 sub folders. I would need to change that channel on frontend everywhere...

From docs I found this:

```
/**
 * The channels the user receives notification broadcasts on.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function receivesBroadcastNotificationsOn()
{
    return 'users.'.$this->id;
}
```

But it is not working, it  is still using `notifiable_type` as channel name.. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify any custom channel name for each **Notifiable entity**. So in case you use the `User` model:

```
# User.php

/**
 * The channels the user receives notification broadcasts on.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function receivesBroadcastNotificationsOn()
{
    return 'users.'.$this->id;
}
```

In case you are using queues, make sure to [update/restart your queue jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#running-the-queue-worker).

Comment: Seems like restarting queue did the job :D

Comment: do you maybe know how to broadcast custom data, when I broadcast array with my data it also sends type and socket and uuid. I don't want those 3...

Comment: Could you provide more info about what ar you really ferrying to? The payload received it or customize it in which way.

Comment: I posted new question :D
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477056/laravel-notification-broadcasting-custom-data

Comment: I mean probably I need uuid for read_at, butt its a little stupid to show my App/Models/User for type :D