# Laravel notification broadcasting custom data

Tags: php, laravel

I have this as broadcasting data:

```
public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
    {
        $avatar = !is_null($this->follower->avatar) ? 'storage/' . $this->follower->id . '/' . $this->follower->avatar->image : '' ;
        return new BroadcastMessage([
            'follower_id' => $this->follower->id,
            'avatar' => $avatar,
            'name' => $this->follower->name,
            'at' => Carbon::now()->format('d/m/Y')
        ]);
    }
```

It does work but I am getting additional type, uuid and socket within this array...
How can I cut those and use just ones that I added?

Comment: Hello Lerner, what kind of data do you want no notify? Even further, for which reasons do you want to make a notification? (I mean, the purpose of the notification). This is because there's two ways to broadcast a notification/event, one more powerful than the other.

Comment: I have some user website, for follow/unfollow and for publishing new posts to send notification to all followers.

Comment: Ok I got it. At the end of the day, this additional info is transparent for the user. You will output/show him/her whatever you want. The Broadcast Notification channel isn't as customizable as a proper Event. You could change your implementation to use Events to fire them to a custom channels and with specific event names instead of Notifications. You could choose that aprpoach

Comment: Well I know that, I am using events for chat broadcasting and it works great, but I thought I would take a shot for notifications since it can handle broadcasting, database and email out of the box. I could create NotificationEvent but I ll try to rewrite this first :D